# JBoss 5.1 Plugin for IntelliJ 14.1.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, application-server

I am looking to setup JBoss 5.1 eas with Intellij 14.1.3. I tried with JetBrain's JBoss Integration plugin version 2.14 (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/218?pr=)

But this does not work. After installing the plugin and restarting the IDE, I'm not able to find the JBoss Server option in the run/debug configurations.

Please let me know if there is any jboss 5.1 plugin available?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, got to know that there is no working JBoss plugin for Intelij 14.x community edition. We need to buy the licensed version to work with JBoss AS.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's right. The JBoss, Tomcat and most application server plugins are only available in the Ulitmate edition. See the **Deployment** section  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html